# How to build a withdrawal-restricted wallet on Ethereum?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to build a wallet such that

- It has a trading dashboard/exchange integrated to it
- The holder of the wallet can trade using this wallet but cannot withdraw capital without the protocol's permission

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check sources of Augur Project, they have exactly the wallet contract you are describing:

```
contract AugurWallet is Initializable, IAugurWallet {
    using SafeMathUint256  for uint256;

    IAugurWalletRegistry public registry;
    mapping(address => bool) public authorizedProxies;

    uint256 private constant MAX_APPROVAL_AMOUNT = 2 ** 256 - 1;

    //keccak256("EIP712Domain(address verifyingContract)");
    bytes32 public constant DOMAIN_SEPARATOR_TYPEHASH = 0x035aff83d86937d35b32e04f0ddc6ff469290eef2f1b692d8a815c89404d4749;

    //keccak256("AugurWalletMessage(bytes message)");
    bytes32 public constant MSG_TYPEHASH = 0xe0e790a7bae5fba0106cf286392dd87dfd6ec8631e5631988133e4470b9e7b0d;

    // bytes4(keccak256("isValidSignature(bytes,bytes)")
    bytes4 constant internal EIP1271_MAGIC_VALUE = 0x20c13b0b;

    address owner;

    bytes32 public domainSeparator;
    IERC20 public cash;

    ... and so on ...

}
```

the "withdrawal" restricted in their implementation is that they lock part of funds as non-withdrawable

https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/blob/dev/packages/augur-core/src/contracts/AugurWallet.sol

Comment: You said, "the 'withdrawal' restricted in their implementation is that they lock part of funds as non-withdrawable"

Where's the definition/implementation of this in the code?

Comment: it is called "frozen funds"